# query 2 record in 1 line

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table like below:

Table "peg":

```
|  id  |  name  |  kode  |
--------------------------
|  P01 |  david | 101    |
```

Table "absen":

```
|  kode |  time               |  ket |
----------------------------------------
|  101 |  2018-01-25 07:00:00 | IN   |
|  101 |  2018-01-25 16:00:00 | OUT  |
```

Please help me how to get the query result as below:

```
|  id  |  name  | kode |      time_1          | ket| time_2             | ket |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  P01 |  david | 101  |  2018-01-25 07:00:00 | IN |2018-01-25 16:00:00 |OUT  |
```

Comment: [Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) mate!

Comment: I don' t think you can make a sql statement that returns dynamic number of columns, as I see in the sample result you have two times because two rows in "absen" are related to "peg", and if you had more rows you will show more columns? or is this fixed?. You also mentioned the php tag. My advice you start with something then post your php and sql code and ask for specific help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1935b1/7). You can do 2 left joins (Aliasing the absen table), to get your result:

```
SELECT peg.*, ab1.time as time_1, ab1.ket as ket, ab2.time as time_2, 
ab2.ket as ket2  FROM peg
LEFT JOIN absen ab1 ON peg.kode = ab1.kode AND ab1.ket = 'IN'
LEFT JOIN absen ab2 ON peg.kode = ab2.kode AND ab2.ket = 'OUT'
```

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui Not sure why the 2 are even needed. He obviously knows time_1 is the IN and time_2 is the OUT.